# Get Categories of Products on Special Offer

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, model, category-products, resource-model

How can I get the list of categories of all the products on special offers. It's a bit tricky. I'm able to get the list of products using:

```
        $collection
          ->addAttributeToFilter(
              array(
                  array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                  array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                  )
            )
          ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
              0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
              1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
          ), 'left')
          ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
              0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
              1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
          ), 'left')
          ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');
```

But how can i get their categories (top level categories preferably).

Thanks.

Comment: Good logical question. +1 for you. Hopefully my answer will resolve your issue.

Comment: How you define a product in special offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already have the products inside the `$collection` object.
You can do this.

```
$categoryIds = array();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
   $categoryIds = array_merge($categoryIds, $product->getCategoryIds());
}
$categoryIds = array_unique($categoryIds);
```

Now you have the category ids you need.
Here is how you can get the top level categories that have ids among the ones you filtered above.

```
if (count($categoryIds) > 0) {
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        //add the attributes you need to the select. * = all.
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        //filter by ids you need
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
        //get only active categories
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        //get only top level categories: 2 means top level (1 is root catalog and 0 is root of all roots)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2)
        //sort by position if needed
        ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC');
}
```

Now you can just loop through the categories collection and do what you need with your category. You don't need to call `load` anymore for each one.

Answer (score 2):

As you said you got product collection let assume product collection is $collection.

```
    $cat = array();
    foreach ($collection as $col) {
        foreach ($col->getCategoryIds() as $catId) {
            //check if category id exist.
            if(!in_array($catId, $cat))
            {
               //push to $cat
                array_push($cat,$catId);
            }
        }
    }
```

$cat variable store category id of products.

Now load category collection by category ids.

```
    $categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $cat));
    foreach ($categoryCollection as $catCol) {
        echo $catCol->getId();
    }
```

This is long way to do this.

or you can set flag as category attribute while special price set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
...
// to get all categories
foreach($collection as $singleProduct)
{
    $categories = $singleProduct->getCategoryIds();
    foreach($categories as $singleCategory)
    {
        array_push($allCategories,$singleCategory);
    }
}
$allCategories = array_unique($allCategories);
...

...
// to get top level categories (which are under default category)
foreach($collection as $singleProduct)
{
    $categories = $singleProduct->getCategoryIds();

    foreach($categories as $singleCategory)
    {
        $CategoryObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($singleCategory);
        if($CategoryObj->getLevel() == 2)       
        {
            array_push($allCategories,$singleCategory);
        }
    }
}
$allCategories = array_unique($allCategories);
...
```

Comment: i was thinking of doing that, but what if i have 500 products on offer, we will be hitting the db 500 times, any other way to do it ?

Comment: I am also using this on my store and I have 3000+ products, I have only this solution. If you find any better way please share.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootCategories = array();
$intRootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($intRootCategoryId);
$subcats = explode(',',$category->getChildren());

foreach($subcats as $cat)
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat)->getProductCollection();
    $collection
      ->addAttributeToFilter(
          array(
              array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
              array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
              )
        )
      ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
          0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
          1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
      ), 'left')
      ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
          0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
          1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
      ), 'left')
      ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');
    if(!empty($collection))       
    {
        array_push($rootCategories,$cat);
    }

}
```